# Android Studio Gradle Sync Failed. Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, drone.io, mavlink

I just can't figure this out and am not sure where to look or how to read the log file. Could anyone help? Is this because of Kotlin?

This is the error message:
Gradle sync failed: Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileResolver;)V
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3s 374ms)

The project is DroidPlanner/Tower from Github. https://github.com/DroidPlanner/Tower.
I can't make it sync...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-------------edit----------------

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'  
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${play_services_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${play_services_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${play_services_version}"

compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_lib_version}"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_lib_version}"
compile "com.android.support:preference-v7:${support_lib_version}"
compile "com.android.support:preference-v14:${support_lib_version}"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_lib_version}"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_lib_version}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${support_lib_version}"

// Android library to display the changelog
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.changeloglib:changelog:2.0.0'

//DroneKit-Android client lib
compile 'com.o3dr.android:dronekit-android:3.0.2'
//Comment line above, and uncomment line below to use your local version of the dronekit-android client lib
//Don't forget to uncomment the lines in the settings.gradle file as well.
//     compile project(':ClientLib')

compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
compile(name:'shimmer-android-release', ext:'aar')
compile(name:'libuvccamera-release', ext:'aar')
compile(name:'sliding-up-panel-3.3.0', ext:'aar')

compile files('libs/droneapi-java-0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('libs/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jeromq-0.3.4.jar')
compile files('libs/sius-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('libs/BaiduLBS_Android.jar')

compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:${okhttp_version}"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:${okhttp_version}"

compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

//Charts and graph library
compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.5@aar'

//Leak canary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary)
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}

def versionPrefix = "Tower-v"

//Decomposed version name and code (https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/6f5TcVPRZij)
def versionMajor = 4
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 10 //bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

//Logging levels
def logLevelVerbose = 2;
def logLevelDebug = 3;
def logLevelInfo = 4;
def logLevelWarn = 5;
def logLevelError = 6;
def logLevelAssert = 7;

android {
compileSdkVersion android_build_sdk_version
buildToolsVersion android_build_tools_version

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'org.droidplanner.android'
    minSdkVersion android_build_min_sdk_version
    targetSdkVersion android_build_target_sdk_version
    versionCode computeVersionCode(versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch, versionBuild)
    versionName generateVersionName(versionPrefix, versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch)

    buildConfigField "boolean", "WRITE_LOG_FILE", "true"
    buildConfigField "int", "LOG_FILE_LEVEL", "$logLevelDebug"
    buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS", "false"

    //Manifest placeholders (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support)
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        fabricApiKey:getFabricApiKey()
    ]

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        jniLibs.srcDir "jni/libs"
    }

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}

//FIXME: remove this after lint errors have been taken care of
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile getAppKeystoreFile()
        storePassword getAppKeystorePassword()
        keyAlias getAppKey()
        keyPassword getAppKeyPassword()
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def file = output.outputFile
        if (file != null && file.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def buildType = variant.buildType.getName()
            def flavorName = variant.getFlavorName()
            def versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode
            output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, "tower-${flavorName}-${buildType}.${versionCode}.apk")
        }
    }
}

android.variantFilter { variant ->
    def flavors = variant.getFlavors()
    if (!flavors.isEmpty()) {
        def flavorName = flavors.get(0).name
        def buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name

        //Filter out the variants we're not interested in building.
        def ignoreVariant = true
        switch (buildTypeName) {
            case "release":
                switch (flavorName) {
                    case "prod":
                    case "beta":
                        ignoreVariant = false
                        break
                }
                break;

            case "debug":
                switch (flavorName) {
                    case "dev":
                        ignoreVariant = false
                        break
                }
                break;
        }

        variant.setIgnore(ignoreVariant);
    }
}

productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Tower Dev"
        resValue "string", "baidu_api_key", ""
        versionName generateVersionName(versionPrefix, versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch, "debug.${versionBuild}")

        //Enable or disable crashlytics based on the availability of the api key
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }

    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Tower Beta"
        resValue "string", "baidu_api_key", "4x7A3lUHEmzFxosafDa4bLP7yinmEnPh"
        versionName generateVersionName(versionPrefix, versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch, "beta.${versionBuild}")

        //Enable or disable crashlytics based on the availability of the api key
        ext.enableCrashlytics = hasFabricApiKey()
    }

    prod {
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Tower"
        resValue "string", "baidu_api_key", "41mPy2URFjOL61GzyWk8U5oLhhwSYGWe"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "WRITE_LOG_FILE", "false"

        //Enable or disable crashlytics based on the availability of the api key
        ext.enableCrashlytics = hasFabricApiKey()
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS", "false"
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_CRASHLYTICS", "${hasFabricApiKey()}"
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
}

/**
 * @return The most recent git tag to be used as version name for the app.
 */
def getGitVersion(){
def cmd = "git describe --tag"
try {
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    return proc.text.trim()
}catch(IOException e){
    //Unable to find 'git'
    return "please update version name manually"
}
}

def getAppKeystoreFile() {
def filePath = hasProperty('ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE') ? ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE : null
return filePath ? file(filePath) : null
}

def getAppKeystorePassword(){
return hasProperty('ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PWD') ? ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PWD : ''
}

def getAppKeyPassword() {
return hasProperty('ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEY_PWD') ? ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEY_PWD : ''
}

def getAppKey() {
return hasProperty('ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS') ? ORG_DROIDPLANNER_ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS : ''
}

def getFabricApiKey(){
return hasFabricApiKey() ? COM_O3DR_FABRIC_API_KEY : ''
}

def hasFabricApiKey(){
return hasProperty('COM_O3DR_FABRIC_API_KEY')
}
```

Comment: try cleaning the project and build it again

Comment: I did. Still no bueno. It suggests that I Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network), but still doesn't work. Will it be because of "play_services_version" in dependencies instead of actual versions in the gradle?

Comment: please add your build.gradle file too

Comment: Just did! Could you take a look?

Comment: where do you live?first of all don't use fabric and use firebase crashlytics api instead. and for your problem if you live in a country which bans the fabric api, you should use vpn to sync the project

Comment: Does it have an effect?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to research on fabric and firebase, so I don't quite follow your answer... I'll probably look into firebase this weekend since real time update led me to that